# Is it possible to free local allocated memory with VirtualFreeEx?

Tags: windows, winapi

Say process 1 has allocated some space with VirtualAlloc in a function and the function already returned at that time. Is it possible that a second process frees the space with VirtualFreeEx if it knows the right address(es)?

Comment: @CareyGregory In fact the answer is very short, but it is yes rather than no.

Comment: why downvote? Is there something not right with my question?

Comment: I asked this question on meta (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157003/why-was-my-admittedly-terse-answer-deleted) and I guess that brought visitors who voted to close and down voted. I don't understand their reasons. Your question was clear, easy to understand, and easy to answer. Both Hans and I answered accurately. I don't think Hans should have deleted his answer. I think some of the problem was that some people failed to understand your question and started making distracting noise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to this question is yes.

Memory is owned by the process in which it resides. It is not owned by the process which allocated it.

In many ways, this is similar to calling `malloc` from one thread and then `free` from another. That's perfectly fine. And it's perfectly fine to do the equivalent with `VirtualAllocEx` and `VirtualFreeEx`.

Comment: Perfectly fine, but maybe not the best possible practice.

Comment: I actually find a lot of Microsoft's documentation to be the opposite: they state what is possible/supported, and if what you want is not on the list, then it's likely not possible, not supported, or both. I don't know of any doc that says, "here are all of the things that <such-and-such> can't do."

Comment: I can confirm the answer. After a few experiments and writing down allocated addresses, it is possible to free them with VirtualFreeEx. Thank you for your answer.